# DOM not visually updating with iOS scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

This is an odd one.

Let's say I have some text in a container with `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` applied to it, and a `span` element with a background color within the content but outside of the viewport.

If you then press a button to remove the `span` element and replace the contents with the text inside, and then scroll the container so that the `span` element that was once there is in the viewport, the background color is retained. The `span` element itself is gone, but the DOM is not visually updated.

### jsFiddle (view it on iOS) - http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/rdZq4/4/

Now, there are two solutions that I have found that I do not like, but update the container visually:

1. Remove the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch`
2. Add the following code to change an aspect of the CSS, then back:

This method uses `.scroll()`:

```
$(".text").scroll(function () {
$(".text").css("color", "blue");
setTimeout(function () {
    $(".text").css("color", "#000");
   }, 1)
});
```

Problem with this, the residual background color is there until the scrolling stops, which still leaves the artifact.

Comment: It appears you have found your self a bug with `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;` have you reported it to WebKit?

Comment: @Steven Nope, I'll do so now.

Comment: If anything they would be able to tell you for sure if it is a bug. But due to the fact that if you are looking at the span when you press clear it works and if you aren't it doesn't. It's most likely a bug. You may also want to report it to Apple.

Comment: How would I report it to Apple? Either way, a potential client side fix would be to change the CSS value of some element on the page as the user is scrolling, I'm just not sure if that event exists.